# How can I hide params in view's url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm passing a change id as a parameter with a `link_to`:

`<%= link_to 'Change', my_service_path(change: '1234567890'), method: :get%>`

In the controller I have:

```
def my_action
   if params[:change]
     ...
     params.delete :change
end
```

But when the `view` is displayed I still see
`<view url>?change=1234567890`

How do I prevent `?change=1234567890` from showing in the url?

Comment: Use POST instead of GET if you don't want the query string on the url. You may need to use a form instead of a link too.

Comment: @arieljuod - That's interesting. How will use of `POST` or a `form` prevent the query parameters from showing in the url?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `params` is an instance of `ActionController::Parameters`, which was specifically created because people were treating the `params` object as a hash, as you're attempting to do.

As @arieljuod suggested, you'll have to convert your route/link to use a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request. That way the params will be sent along with the HTTP headers instead of showing up in the URL bar as a query string.

So in your case:

```
<%= link_to 'Change', my_service_path(change: '1234567890'), method: :post %>
```

...and make sure your route is configured to respond to a `POST` request

Comment: Good answer, but will probably result in unintended consequences and loss of state - especially when someone pushes back on their browser or reloads the page when the params are missing.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do, "Change", says to me you're trying to modify the state of a resource.  In RESTful design, you should be `PATCH`ing, not `GET`'ing.

The way you'd hide the params is to create a form, put `change` in a hidden field, and submit the form as a PATCH request using a `button_tag`.

In Slim, it would look like this:

```
= form_tag(url: my_service_url, method: :patch) do
  = hidden_field_tag(:change, "123456789")
  = submit_tag("Change")
```

On your website, it will look just like a regular link - but instead you are instructing the Rails server to EDIT the resource, not GET it.

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question in the comments:

> How will use of POST or a form prevent the query parameters from showing in the > url?

If you send a POST request, your request will have a body, too. So in the GET request from your link will send the change information via the url. In a POST request (use `button_to` or form) it will send via the body and not displayed in the url. You can then still access it via the params